# Add data to csv file in specific columns using PHP

Tags: php, database, csv, fputcsv

I have a csv file which has 14 columns, and hundreds of rows. There is a header which is `"sku","category","description","brand"` etc.

All data is allready there but I'm trying to add some image filenames inside the CSV, in some specific columns `( "images", "small_image" , "thumnail" ).`

The header kind of looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------+------+
| sku | category | description | image | small_image | thumbnail |  price | color|
+-----+----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------+------+
```

so knowing how the header looks like, then the first row would be like:

```
+-------+---------------+------------------+---+---+----+-----+--------+
| sku01 | category name | description here |   |   |    | 99$ | black  |
+-------+---------------+------------------+---+---+----+-----+--------+
```

The filename for the jpeg is the same as the `sku` value on the same row , with the jpeg extension. So for example, if there is `sku01` for the `sku` column on the first row, the filename would be `sku01.jpeg` in the image column on that same row. So would be the small_image value, and the thumbnail value.

**However the filename would only be specified IF the jpeg exist in a folder.**

So far I know how to use the fopen function to open the csv file, eventually store all data in an array ( I don't know if that would help in my case ) , then at some point use the fputcsv function after checking if file_exist in the specific folder on the server.

But, to me it's still a big mess in my head as far as in what order I should use the functions. I 'm stuck. Also, I have no idea how to put the jpeg filename in the right columns ( image, thumbnail, small_image), because these columns are in the "middle" of the csv file, among other columns. They are not at the end of the csv file

I would be really thankful to anyone who can put me on the right path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you should first break out your columns into an array exactly as they appear in your raw csv file:

```
$columns = ["sku","category","description","image","small_image","thumbnail", "price","color"];
```

Then you'll want to open the file and iterate over it, building an associative array of key-value pairs, checking whether or not a file exists for that image name, and if so, assigning the correct name to the array.

```
$rootDir = ""; //Root directory where your image files are located
$file = fopen("filehandle.csv", "r"); //Open the old file for reading
$newFile = fopen("newfilehandle.csv", "w"); //Create a new file for writing

while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $row = array_combine($columns, $data);
    $filename = "{$row['sku']}.jpeg";
    if (file_exists("$rootDir/$filename")) {
        $row['image'] = $filename;
        $row['small_image'] = $filename;
        $row['thumbnail'] =  $filename; 
    }
    fputcsv($newFile, array_values($row)); //write data into new file
}

fclose($file);
fclose($newFile);
```

Now you have a copy of the original file with the new values inserted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I get the idea. I have no clue on how to put the values back in the CSV. Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/v1QQpaSv

Comment: Thanks, however i'm still having problems, I'm probably doing something wrong because I get an error : Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Comment: It's possible your csv files have an encoding issue. Do me a favor and goto terminal. Locate the directory where your file is stored and run `file file.csv` where 'file.csv' is the name of your file. Post the output here.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it finally worked! There were a couple issues. You were right, when I checked in notepad++ it was in ANSI, I encoded it in UTF-8. Also $data['sku'] gave the following error : Undefined index: sku , I changed to $row['sku'] . The new csv file is created with the correct data inside. Thank you very much for your detailed reply and the follow-up, really appreciated , i'd like to send you a few $ via paypal to thank you because you really helped me out here, you can drop me a mail on mlclm (dot) design (at) gmail (dot) com to let me know your paypal address

Comment: while I appreciate your offer, I'm more than happy to help, free of charge :)